# asp.net c# force page reload on browser print hotkey

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, printing

Is there any way to run code in my asp.net c# web application if the print hotkey (ctrl+P) is pressed by the user?

I have an multiline asp:TextBox and I need to calculate the number of rows to generate the correct height of the textbox for the document. Atm I have an Print- Button, which works really fine, but I want to run the same code if the browser print function is used by the user.

Thank you in advance

Comment: why not use Javascript to calculate the rows, instead? Then you don't need a request to the server.

Comment: That would be possible too but I prefer the solution with server request because I can do some additional stuff in one step. Thank you anyway, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this in Webforms. Make a dummy `Button` or `LinkButton` and trigger the click on that with jQuery when Control+P is pressed. Then in code behind write `window.print()` to the page with the `ScriptManager`.

The `<span>` element in the LinkButton is needed to register the click.

```
<script>
    $(window).bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase() === 'P') {
            $('#LinkButton1')[0].click(); 
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><span></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

And then the code

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "PrintWindow", "window.print()", true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I love that solution